# KARATE : can not see print statements on console in karate

Tags: karate

KARATE : can not see print statements on console in karate
I am unable to see print statements on console when I write print statements in feature file using javascript
here is my code :

```
Scenario: Get list of channels
    Given url 'https://slack.com/api/channels.list?token=''
    When method get
    Then status 200
  * print 'Response is: 'response
  * def obj = (response.channels[0].length)
  * print 'LENGTH OF AN ARRAY IS: 'obj
```

Comment: its resolved , i checked the docum , i had forgotten to give comma

Comment: please add an answer and mark i t as accepted here (yourself) to help others

Comment: before : print 'LENGTH OF AN ARRAY IS: 'obj After: print 'LENGTH OF AN ARRAY IS: '**,obj**

Comment: no I meant post an answer below (not as a comment) and after 2 days, mark it as accepted. it is up to you, but I'd like to not have "un-answered" questions lying around on Stack Overflow. or please delete this question

Comment: Thank you peter for prompt response , great :)

Answer (score 4):

**before** (problem):

```
print 'LENGTH OF AN ARRAY IS: 'obj
```

**After** (fixed):

```
print 'LENGTH OF AN ARRAY IS: ', obj
```

Answer (score 1):

put (,) between parameter

- print 'Response is: ', response