# Printing to console not working in Karate

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have scenario which tests an Micro service.
  Scenario Outline: Run Object Queries

```
Scenario Outline: Run Object Queries
    Given url homeLinks.queryUrl
    And header Content-Type =  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then print response
```

Print statement is not logging anything to console in InteliJ editor. I tried to run in debug mode as well.

I referred [KARATE : can not see print statements on console in karate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320169/karate-can-not-see-print-statements-on-console-in-karate) which didn't help.

Any config changes required to print the logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally people don't run into issues. Refer the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging

If you have mixed Karate into a project with a lot of other dependencies this may happen. I suggest you try the Maven quickstart and that will work correctly out of the box: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

Then it is a matter of comparing the setup with your project. If you still get stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Issue was in logback-test.xml.
After comparing with quickstart project it worked. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

In logback-test.xml under test/resources, When I change the Console level from WARN to INFO, I can see the logs. My application is spring boot application

```html
<root level="INFO" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="Console" />
 </root>
```